# Show that $v$ is harmonic and rotation invariant iff $v(z)=A\log |z|+B$ for some constants $A$ and $B$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions, analyticity

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and $v$ be a function on $\Omega.$ Suppose that $v(z)$ depends only on $|z|$ and not on arg$z.$ Show that $v$ is harmonic if and only if  $v(z)=A\log |z|+B$ for some constants $A$ and $B$.

Any hint. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MyGlasses ya statement is like this .

Comment: I edited your post and took the word "harmonic" out of the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe we may write

$z = re^{i\theta} = \vert z \vert \exp(i\arg z); \tag 0$

then $\vert z \vert = r$ and $\theta = \arg z$; we see that since $v(z)$ does not depend on $\theta$, $\partial v / \partial \theta = 0$, whence:

The suggested answer our OP Eklavya deleted as owner was on the right track insofar as it suggested looking at the Laplacian of $v$ in polar coordinates, *viz.*

$\dfrac{\partial^2v}{\partial r^2} + \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial r} + \dfrac{1}{r^2}\dfrac{\partial^2v}{\partial \theta^2}= 0; \tag 1$

since $v$ is "rotation invariant"; for convenience with typing $\LaTeX$, I am going to adopt the abbreviation

$v_r = \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial r}, \tag 2$

so that (1) becomes

$v_{rr}+ \dfrac{1}{r} v_r = 0, \tag 3$

which, in a vicinity where $v_r \ne 0$, may be written

$\dfrac{v_{rr}}{v_r} = -\dfrac{1}{r}, \tag 4$

or

$(\ln v_r)_r = -\dfrac{1}{r}, \tag 5$

which may be integrated with respect to $r$ to yield

$\ln v_r(r) - \ln v_r(r_0) = \displaystyle \int_{r_0}^r (\ln v_r(s))ds = -\int_{r_0}^r \dfrac{1}{s} ds = \ln r_0 - \ln r, \tag 6$

or

$\ln(\dfrac{v_r(r)}{v_r(r_0)}) = \ln \dfrac{r_0}{r}; \tag 7$

we exponentiate,

$\dfrac{v_r(r)}{v_r(r_0)} = \dfrac{r_0}{r}; \tag 8$

thus

$v_r(r) = \dfrac{v_r(r_0)r_0}{r}; \tag 9$

we may integrate (9) again,

$v(r) - v(r_0) = \displaystyle \int_{r_0}^r v_r(s) ds =  \int_{r_0}^r \dfrac{v_r(r_0)r_0}{s}ds = v_r(r_0)r_0(\ln r -\ln r_0), \tag{10}$

finally,

$v(r) =  v_r(r_0)r_0\ln r - v_r(r_0)r_0\ln r_0 + v(r_0), \tag{11}$

thus

$v(z) = v(r) = A\ln \vert z \vert + B, \tag{12}$

where

$A = v_r(r_0)r_0 \tag{13}$

and

$B = -v_r(r_0)r_0\ln r_0 + v(r_0). \tag{14}$

Likewise, if $v(r)$ is as in (12), it is easy to see (3) binds, so $v(r)$ is harmonic.